# Why Bit-PLRU is different from LRU

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Following is description  about bit-plru

> Bit-PLRU stores one status bit for each cache line. We call these bits MRU-
>    bits. Every access to a line sets its MRU-bit to 1, indicating that the line  was recently used. Whenever the last remaining 0 bit of a set's status bits  is set to 1, all other bits are reset to 0. At cache misses, the line with  lowest index whose MRU-bit is 0 is replaced.

I think both replace policy of lru and bit-plru are same, their miss rate are also same.

My reason:  `At cache misses, the line with  lowest index whose MRU-bit is 0 is replaced.`

Line with lowest index means least recently used, so its mru-bit is definitely zero(it couldn't be 1 because it isn't recently used). So, mru-bit is redundant?

If my reason is wrong, could anyone give me some reason or example show me where is different between bit-plru and lru? Why bit-plru gave better performance(miss rate)?

Thanks!

Comment: For an associativity of 2, plru and lru they are equivalent. But otherwise, it is impossible. For instance with an associativity of 4, if you want to order the lines by access time, there are 4*3*2 different orders. You cant do that with 4 bits. plru garanties that the most recent will not be ejected, but not that the least recent will be.

Comment: Isn't `least recent used` means `not most recent`, so lru 
 garanties not replace least recent used data?

Comment: can you give me some real example, I still can't make real example by myself, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Least recently used means the line with the oldest access time. But keeping track of accesses to always know which one is the oldest may be complex in a cache context. Storing the access order for every block would require at least ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(*n*!)) bits, or, most probably, *n*×log<sub>2</sub>n bits which is close for *n* small and much simpler to manage. Whenever a memory reference is accessed, it must be removed from the order list, put at the top and the rest of the list updated. This may be complex to do in *one* cycle.

This is the reason why pseudo-LRU methods have been developed. They guaranty that an "ancient" line will be ejected, but not that the most ancient will be.

Consider an example for the bit-LRU of your question. We assume that the initial set state is the following.

```
line    status    real order
(index) (MRU)
0       0         3  LRU
1       1         0  MRU
2       1         1
3       0         2
```

The real order is not stored, but we will use it to understand the behavior of the algorithm (smallest is youngest).

Now, assume we access existing line 0. Status becomes

```
line    status    real order
(index) (MRU)
0       1         0  MRU
1       1         1  
2       1         2
3       0         3  LRU
```

Assume this is followed by a miss, so we apply the method and replace line 3:

> Whenever the last remaining 0 bit of a set's status bits is set to 1, all other bits are reset to 0.

```
line    status    real order
(index) (MRU)
0       0         1  
1       0         2  
2       0         3  LRU
3       1         0  MRU
```

So the algorithm has properly ejected LRU (line 3).

Assume that there is another miss. The algorithm states :

> At cache misses, the line with lowest index whose MRU-bit is 0 is replaced.

So line 0 will be replaced. But it is **not** LRU which is line 2. It is even the "youngest" in the ancient lines. But is has the lowest index.
To eject another better line would require additional information on the access times.
Maybe some randomness in the ejection could be simply added. But finding the real LRU is more complex.

Note that there are better ways to have a pseudo LRU. Tree-LRU for instance is much better, but it still does not guaranty that the real LRU will be used.
For practical applications, pLRU gives a miss rate similar to real LRU, while being much simpler.

But even real LRU may not always be the best policy  and if a line has been accessed frequently it is likely that it will continue to be accessed, and it should probably not be replaced even if it is LRU.
So the most efficient methods extend pLRU by keeping track of the number of accesses and by considering differently  lines that are have been accessed only once and lines that have been accessed twice or more. This way, whenever a line has to be ejected, lines that have been accessed only once are preferred.